# не работает php

Tags: php

Учу HTML дошёл до form начал углубляться в тему и дошёл до обработчиков форм PHP. Начал практиковаться в  Notepad++ написал обычную форму для сообщений и подключил файл php (action="index.php"),  а в файле написал 
всё просто но не работает, открывает текст php.

```
<form name="form1" action="index.php" method="post">
<label>Email:</label> <br /> 
<input name="email" type="text" /> <br />
<label>Name</label> <br />
<input name="name" type="text" /> <br />
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Ready" /> <br />
<p><textarea name="masege" cols="40" rows="20"></textarea></p>
</form>
```

Comment: <form name="form1"  action="index.php" method="post">
        <label>Email:</label> <br />
 <input name="email" type="text" /> <br />
 <label>Name</label> <br />
 <input name="name" type="text" /> <br />
 <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Ready" /> <br />
 <p><textarea name="masege" cols="40" rows="20"></textarea></p>
</form>

Comment: если у вас файлы на рабочем столе просто так лежат, то так и будет. Почитайте что такое пхп вообще, кто его выполняет. Это не html страница, которую показывает браузер, это серверная часть, требующая установки соответствующего ПО

Comment: чтобы обрабатывать язык `php` вам нужен сервер, установите хотя бы `apache`

Comment: OpenServer лучше сразу.

Comment: Спасибо большое

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для начала вам нужен установленный php. Ваш html обрабатывает и рендерит браузер, а вот php интерпретировать браузер не умеет. А у меет это длать интерпретатор php (или просто php). Как установить php читайте в соответствующем разделе документации -- https://www.php.net/manual/ru/install.windows.php (у вас же виндоуз?).

После того как вы установили php (и смогли в cmd запустить `php -v`), вам потребуется [веб-север](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B5%D0%B1-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80). Веб-сервер это программа, которая обрабатывает [HTTP](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP)-запросы из браузера. То есть, которая отдаёт в браузер html-странички в зависимости от запроса.

Для знакомства и на старте изучения php поще всего воспользоваться веб-сервером, который поставляется вместе с php -- https://www.php.net/manual/ru/features.commandline.webserver.php. Он уже есть у вас и дополнительно устанавливать ничего не надо.

Откройте cmd, переключитесь  папку со своим проектом и введите команду `php -S localhost:8000`. Это запустит веб-сервер по адресу `http://localhost:8000`. Обратите внимание, что веб-сервер не завершается после ввода команды, а "зависает". Он постоянно ожидает новых запросов и будет работать пока вы не нажмёте в окне cmd `ctrl+C` или просто не закроете это окно.

Я сделал от такую структуру файлов:

```
learnPHP/
├── formHandler.php
└── index.html
```

Далее открываете cmd переключаетесь в директорию `learnPHP`, после чего вводите `php -S localhost:8000`. Нажимаете энтер и увидите что-то вроде:

```
PHP 7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Development Server started at Thu Dec 12 11:32:11 2019
Listening on http://localhost:8000
Document root is /home/egor/projects/lab/learnPHP
Press Ctrl-C to quit.
```

Теперь открывайте в браузере http://localhost:8000 и увидите сраничку index.html. Если открыть http://localhost:8000/formHandler.php, то отработает скрипт formHandler.php.